# Sound Design Behind This Future Bass Lead

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects

In the following song, it seems like the lead instrument is some sort of vocal or something. What would be a good way of replicating that sort of song using a synth or sampler etc? The lead enters at around 0:24.

Song:

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to post a different clip?  I don't hear a lead entering at approximately 0:24.

Comment: It's actually at 0:26...it's basically the part that sounds like someone is soloing. You're hearing the "Kermode & Sam Winter" track right? You can hear the "lead" part isolated at 0:31-0:32.

Comment: I just don't hear what you're describing.  Nothing remotely like a vocal, and I don't hear a new instrument coming in at 0:26.  I do hear a new line coming in at 0:12, and at the beginning it sounds a bit like a cartoon voice, but then it sounds more instrumental.

Comment: Yes, that cartoon voice that you're describing is what I'm talking about. To me it sounds like a sampled vocal that was modified to sound like an instrument.

Comment: Maybe so.  But doesn't it start at 0:12? And why do you call it "future bass lead"? // Would you like to try to replicate the same steps you think were originally carried out? // (You like the sound?)

Comment: Yes, I would like to replicate that sound. Do I like it? I think it's an interesting sound, that's for sure.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it starts at 0:12, but it's timbre really changes at around 0:26 and perhaps some different process was used at that point.

Comment: So, can you record a voice and then try to chipmunk-ize it?  (No, I don't care for it, but that doesn't matter.)  // Whew, glad to hear I was listening to the same thing you were.

Comment: Future bass is the sub-genre of EDM that this song is a part of. I call it a lead because it carries the melody for the track.

Comment: Lead, I understand.  Future bass -- that was the part that was new to me.  Thanks for explaining.

Comment: I understand the "chipmunk-izing" as you call it, but I'm interested in how they changed the timbre later on. Making it sound like a chipmunk can be done by applying a pitch shift.

Comment: I'm not the right person to answer that, but I think if you narrow down the time segment a whole lot more, you'll get a more useful answer.  I hear several different effects in this track, at different points.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a granular synth/sampler on the chipmunked voice. Watch this and you'll kinda get an idea of what they can do to vocals.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a vocoder, maybe a vocoder with a sidechain (I'm talking as a happy user of Logic X, so I don't know what is possible in other software).

I just did this with a "singing" version of your first sentence:

https://soundcloud.com/straighttoaudio/future-bass-sound-design-se/s-M4MRz

See a really good howto here:

Comment: Hi Hans, thanks for the answer. I'm an avid user of Logic Pro X as well. Unfortunately, this sounds nothing like a vocoder in my opinion. I've used the EVOC20 many times. It seems like some other sort of processing is performed on the vocals. Thanks for the attempt.